# Ajax post is not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

My code is;

```
$.ajax({

      type: "POST",
      url: "mailyaz.php",
      data: {
      name: "testest"
      }
      });
```

This works with simple "testest" message. But I need to post my javascript variable (var mysubject = blabla). If I replace "testest" with mysubject, its not working.

Comment: Please can you define `"not working"`... Are you getting any errors? Is your server's log registering an incoming
 request?

Comment: Can you perhaps show the code that represents the problem, rather than show working code and telling us that some other code has a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var` declares the variable within its function scope only. So make sure your AJAX call is within that function (or remove the `var` - which declares the variable in global scope).

`mysubject` sounds like submitting form data. Try `$('form#myformid').serialize()` instead of the data property if you want to submit form data over your AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks mate, worked. Couldn't understand why those people all neg repped me.

Comment: So you suggest using jquery.post to send this ? Otherwise don't know how to send $('form#myformid').serialize()

Comment: try `$.post('url.php', $('form').serialize(), function(response) { /* .. */ }, 'json')`. With that you'll send the form variables to `url.php`, expecting JSON as response. That's what I'm using. But I suggest, if you have any further questions, create a new question, it's hard to answer with comments (less space, less code indention, ..)

Comment: I posted here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665912/ajax-post-onbeforeunload-doesnt-work/10666572#10666572