# Ajax post onbeforeunload doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This code stores mouse movement coordinates in array and it should post it onbeforeunload. But it doesn't post. If I change

name: moves
to
name: "blabla"

it works. Means that the problem is on the "moves" variable. How can I make it working ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){


var moves = [];

$("html").mousemove(function(e){
moves.push(e.pageX + "x" + e.pageY) 
});


window.onbeforeunload = function() {

$.ajax({

      type: "POST",
      url: "mailyaz.php",
      data: {
      name: moves;
      }
      });

});

});
```

Comment: Your doing asynchronous stuff while reloading/closing the page, it will be buggy. Set `async:false` to wait for the function to finish, it's the only way I know of to make sure it gets thru to the server, otherwise there will be trouble in some browsers, and it will not always go thru.

Comment: Not sure, but the reason it works with just a small string and not the array, which would be huge after just a few seconds of mouse movement, could be the size of the thing, check the console in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gAsKb/)

Comment: I have noticed that the problem is probably on the "moves". It doesnt store it.

Comment: You're closing the window before the ajax request has finished sending the large array, again, to make sure it finishes you will have to do it synchronously and wait for the call to finish before the page can be closed.

Comment: Why don't you send the moves continiously instead of all-at-once? My previous speaker is absolutely right: onbeforeunload is a last-chance-do-something-quick and more important, it is expected to return a confirmation dialog message.

Comment: The idea here is to store every mouse move in a variable, and when visitor is going out (before unload) send request and save the variable. So in which event do you suggest to send request, I didnt understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.
It's a little example that I develop some months ago.
In this case the coordinates are stored in a Text File, but you can replace this with an INSERT into a DataBase.

On the client Side put this:

```
    var moves = ""; //Now an String to store the Coords

    $(document).ready(function(){
        //When you moves the mouse inside the Page then 
        //concat the Coords into the String var and add a Line-Brak at the end
        $("html").mousemove(function(e){
            moves += (e.pageX + " x " + e.pageY + "\n");

        });

        //Here the magic happen: bind a function to onbeforeunload event that POST
        //the String to the server
        $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {

            $.post("server.php",{name:moves});

        }); 

    });
```

Now you need a Page in the server side called server.php which contains

```
    //Capture the String
    $cursorMoves = ($_POST['name']);

    $myFile = "testFile.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
    fwrite($fh, $cursorMoves);
    fclose($fh);
```

Comment: @user198989 I tested it on Chrome 18.0.1025.162 and Firefox 12 and works great!, If you give me an e-mail I can send you the entire project.

Comment: Oh, I noticed that I am using an if statement like if($_POST[name]) {
I removed it and its working now.

Comment: Is it possible to add "," between values ?

Comment: @user198989 Check the code again; I’ve made some changes in order to improve the speed, now I use a String VAR to store the coords, and now the coordinates are separated by Line-Breaks, you can replace this Line-Breaks by any char you want. Regards

Comment: Yes, this is much better. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`onbeforeunload` must return a string. However, the ajax request will be blocked by the dialog that is displayed. If the user accepts and leaves the page, it is likely that the request would be interrupted.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

http://jsfiddle.net/sVU7K/1

Comment: I accidently had mootools set as the lib.  Fixed in this version.  If you cancel the `dialog` You will see the returned request in the console.

Comment: Nothing wrong with onbefore unload. As I said, if I change the variable to "blabla", it works.