# window.onbeforeunload submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with Facebook's sharing feature and currently it's setup to use on a private computer. Meaning, once the person shares something, they will still be logged in.

The problem I'm having is that once the user clicks share, it closes the window right after.

I was hoping that I would have some luck using `window.onbeforeunload`. I'm trying to run this code, before the window closes. And I thought doing something like this would allow it to work. Not having any luck though.

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  $('#logout_form').submit();

}
```

Comment: Do you want the window to remain open after this code is run? If not, then I would try with setTimeout API to let my code run and then let the browser close. You need to think through a bit, though.

Comment: I don't think the browsers would let a form be submitted during the unload event, as this would cause a new HTTP request to be issued and followed, in essence ignoring the user command to close the window. You may be able to get away with issuing an AJAX request, though - is there some way you can use that to accomplish what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

The **only** thing you can reliably do during an `onbeforeonload` handler is decide whether to pop up a confirmation dialog. You cannot trigger new actions, such as submitting a form, from such a handler.

Answer (score 0):

duskwuff is correct that you can't submit a form.  but there are somethings you can do.  I've used Atmosphere and it makes an ajax call on the unload.

```
jQuery(window).unload(function() {
    jQuery.atmosphere.unsubscribe();
});
```

which makes an request call.  You should be able to make an ajax post to the server.

I found a similar example: 
[Ajax post onbeforeunload doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665912/ajax-post-onbeforeunload-doesnt-work)